# C# Повторный запуск потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Разрабатываю сервер на C#. У меня есть интерйфейс, и вся основная сетевая работа выполняется в отдельном потоке. Интерфейсом я управляю состоянием сервера и высматриваю подключенных клиентов.

Суть.

Есть поток, отвечающий за сетевое взаимодействие:

```
static Thread listener = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (currentStatus == Status.on)
            {
                // some work
            }
        });
```

Как вы видите, он работает только пока `currentStatus == Status.on`. Этот `currentStatus` я меняю кнопкой интерфейса. И при запуске, т.е. когда `currentStatus` становится `Status.on` я запускаю поток `listener.Start()`.

Когда я выключаю сервер, т.е. когда `currentStatus` становится `Status.off`, поток по идее уже отработал свой код и вырубился.

В дальнейшем, если мне необходимо, допустим, снова запустить сервер, поток выбрасывает `ThreadStateException: 'Поток выполняется или прерван; его нельзя запустить повторно.'`

Это уничтожает мой мозг, т.к. в моём понимании, отработавший поток должен перейти в то состояние, из которого его можно запустить снова.

Так вот, уважаемые аноны, вопрос:

Как проще всего осуществить перезапуск потока?

Comment: Кстати, хотелось бы увидеть определиние переменной `currentStatus`. Чую распространённую ошибку...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Status currentStatus;

Comment: Угу, классический баг. По крайней мере, используйте [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). А лучше - [CancellationToken](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам не нужно перезапускать поток, по-хорошему нужно сделать так:

```
var evt = new AutoResetEvent(true);

Thread listener = new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        evt.WaitOne();
        while (currentStatus == Status.on)
        {
            // some work
        }
    }
});
```

Если вам нужно запустить внутренний цикл, вы просто вызываете:

```
evt.Set();
```

Если поток находится на строчке `evt.WaitOne();` он потребляет примерно ноль ресурсов CPU.

В этом случае желательно поток отметить как дочерний (`IsBackground = true`), так как без этого поток может не завершиться с завершением основного потока приложения и тем самым может помешать умереть процессу

Comment: В этом случае желательно поток отметить как дочерний (`IsBackground = true`), так как без этого поток может не завершиться с завершением основного потока приложения и тем самым может помешать умереть процессу

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 3):

Из документации ([Состояния управляемых потоков](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-thread-states)):

> Если поток был выведен из состояния Unstarted в результате вызова метода Start, он не может вернуться в состояние Unstarted ни при каких условиях. Поток никогда не может выйти из состояния Stopped.

Дополнительно можно почитать [Состояния потока](http://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/CSThreading1.xml#EGHAG). Оригинал: [ThreadState](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_ThreadState).

---

Умерла, значит умерла... Если нужно запустить *новый* поток, так *создайте новый* поток.